# Dealing with variable certainty in categorical data

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I have a question regarding statistical analyses for categorical variables. Without complicating it, I would like to know how you can deal with uncertain categorical data. That is, categorical data that have associated confidence levels that range from 1-99%. Here is a screenshot of the spreadsheet the data have been inputed in to.

[image]

Are there statistical analyses that can deal with this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are considering the features in the framework of supervised learning.

You can create for each feature few derived features based on the confidence level.
After that, use [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) to choose those that serve you most.

The most straight forward way to derive features based on confidence is to set some levels of confidence ( e.g., above 90%, above 80%,...). If the confidence level in a record is high enough, use it. other wise use null.

More advanced ways are binning according to the confidence distribution of each feature (where you can use equal with bin, equal depth bins) or discretisation with respect to the concept (e.g., minimal mutual information loss).

If you'll choose ten thresholds,  then the initial number of features will be ten times larger. Quite high but still OK.

After you will have the set of features, you will need an evaluation function for the feature selection. I guess that the higher the confidence you'll have, the lower the noise you will have. At a given point, you might lose too mush of the signal. At this point, evaluate them against the concept and see how to advance further.

Comment: To give you more background on the data I have collected -  I have a dataset where we have 23 video clips that have been treated using three different algorithms to change how each clips looks. Each treatment has then been viewed by a number of scientists to try and identify the species in each clip. These reviewers were asked to classify the species in each clip at the order, family, genus and species level and provide an associated confidence level (%) for each classification - see screenshot above I have just added.

Comment: Instead of discarding data I want to compare categorical data and their associated confidence simultaneously across reviewers and treatments. For example, for treatment 1, 4 reviewers identified the species as 'x' at 40, 50, 60 and 70% confidence respectively. The 5th reviewer identified it as 'y' at 30% confidence. For treatment 2, all reviewers identified the species as 'x' at 80, 80, 90, 90 and 100% respectively. Specifically, I want to quantify the change between treatments and reviewers in terms of categorical and numerical data (which are essentially coupled) if that makes sense?

Comment: If you have only 23 samples this method won't work. Actually this is a very low number of samples so uncertainty is due to the data no matter which algorithm you will use. In this case I would have work with a single threshold of confidence. You do have the information about the species that actually appear in the clips, right? If so you can choose the threshold as the one the leads to the highest accuracy or optimum of other loss function.

Comment: I see what you mean, Dan. Problem is, this work was conducted outside of a controlled environment i.e. we cannot be 100% sure of the species appearing in the clips. Maybe I am over complicating it? Maybe I should revert to simple descriptive statistics like average confidence across all experts and clips for each treatment?

Comment: The main thing you are looking for is to evaluate the impact of the algorithms, right? If so, I think that you should indeed use a very simple measure for confidence and go ahead to evaluate the treatment. Try to find a threshold for the votes (e.g., a single vote of confidence above 90%, two votes with confidence above 80%). Try to estimate the precision of the votes above the thresholds (a sanity check to see people don't imagine species).  Once you do that, move back to you original question and check which algorithm leads to more species finding.

Comment: Note that the confidence of your results is limited due to the small dataset. Another point that disturb me is that you are not sure of the actual species in the clips. Try to cope with that issue - Are there few clips for which you are sure of the content? Can you generate such a clip? It will be pity to have unneeded uncertainty in the roots of your investigation.

Comment: Thanks again for the input Dan, much appreciated. We see this as a pilot  study and agree that we should retest these algortihms in aquaria with species of known identity.Unfortunately the uncertainty inherent in this study is unavoidable. If the expert reviewers can reach a consensus on the species independently then that may be a good indication of how likely it is to be that species in reality.